# Match with substring in mongodb aggregation

Tags: regex, mongodb

In my mongodb collection, I have a time_stamp=**"2013-06-30 23:58:37 928"**.
I need to use "**$match**" with only the date, like time_stamp="**2013-06-30**". So how can I get the substring like that ?

Previously I've tried with $substr, but it shows an error **"errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator: $substr"**

Comment: This is so common that there's a cookbook page with the pattern: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/ it works with strings as shown in one of the answers.

Comment: Also, you marked as an answer the option that won't use an index. It will need to do a full collection scan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are trying to make query using aggregation framework since you tried [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) & [$substr](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) operators. I have created a simple example to show how you can use [$substr](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) to achive result you wanted on aggregation framework.

I have inserted following data into the MongoDB.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528b343881d4fe2cfe0b1b25"), "time_stamp" : "2013-06-30 23:58:37 928" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528b343b81d4fe2cfe0b1b26"), "time_stamp" : "2013-06-30 23:58:37 928" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528b344c81d4fe2cfe0b1b27"), "time_stamp" : "2013-06-30 12:58:37 928" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528b344f81d4fe2cfe0b1b28"), "time_stamp" : "2013-06-30 12:58:23 928" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528b345381d4fe2cfe0b1b29"), "time_stamp" : "2013-06-31 12:58:23 928" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528b345981d4fe2cfe0b1b2a"), "time_stamp" : "2013-07-31 12:58:23 933" }
```

I wrote following code to group by date by using [$substr](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) operator.

```
db.myObject.aggregate(
{$project : {new_time_stamp : {$substr : ["$time_stamp",0, 10]}}},
{$group:{_id:"$new_time_stamp", "count": {$sum:1}}}
);
```

Comment: Is the third argument the end index or the length of the substring, can't see anything in the documentation.

Comment: Looks like it's the length.

Answer (score 3):

`$substr` operation failed because you there is no such operation for find. You can only use it in [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/). You mentioned that you have a timestamp. In such a case you need to query [by time interval](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/).

```
{time_stamp: {
  $gte: ISODate("2013-06-30T00:00:00Z"),
  $lt: ISODate("2013-06-31T00:00:00Z")
}}
```

I hope that this month has 31 days. If it is a string ( which is really bad because dates should be stored as dates) you have to use a regex.

Comment: Assuming this field is indexed, this would be more efficient than using aggregation framework. +1