# limit the data returned by model.find() in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to limit the length of data returned by Model.find() in mongodb/mongoose

here is my code 
Want to return 'Excerpt' from content.

```
Blog.find({},{
    title: 1,
    content: 1 // basically wants to return content not more than 200 character
    }, function(err, data){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    res.render('blog/posts', {
        title:'All posts',
        posts: data 
    });
});
```

In other words how to return limited content from mongoDB

**Update**
*Found solution:*

[Match with substring in mongodb aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066279/match-with-substring-in-mongodb-aggregation)

Comment: Did you try with `filter` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/

Comment: Filter returns the document which fulfill a certain criteria but it i want to return all documents but sliced >> eg. if the document has entry like 'this is very long text to show' , i want to return only  'this is very ..'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Match with substring in mongodb aggregation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066279/match-with-substring-in-mongodb-aggregation)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass limit parameter in 3rd option

```
Blog.find({},{
        title: 1,
        content: 1 // basically wants to return content not more than 200 character
    },{ limit:10 }, function(err, data){
    if (err) {
        // You should handle this err because res.render will send
        // undefined if you don't.
        console.log(err);
    }
    res.render('blog/posts', {
        title:'All posts',
        posts: data 
    });
});
```

Comment: it limits json object not the length of data ie. if previously it was returning 100 records, now it will returning only 10 records.....as per this code

Comment: so what else you want do you want is like it should return you 100 documents and length of data should be 10?. whats the logic behind this and please clear what exactly you want so we can help.

Comment: found a solution, i was looking for some like

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066279/match-with-substring-in-mongodb-aggregation
@ShumiGupta