# Aggregation by substring in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have a set of objects like:

```
{
  "_id":"mongoid",
  "requests": {
     "uri": "test.php",
     "clicks" : 15
   },
},
{
  "_id":"mongoid",
  "requests": {
     "uri": "test.php/",
     "clicks" : 10
   }
}
```

Is it possible to make aggregation by field `requests.uri` ("test.php" and "test.php/" must be understood by Mongo as the same) to get clicks in sum 25? Mongo version is 3.2.
I watch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066279/match-with-substring-in-mongodb-aggregation), but the main difference is that `uri` can have various length. 
Thanks to everybody for help.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean here and the complexity would vary by string. The "aggregation framework" allows some types of string manipulation and could theoretically "split" a string on characters like `/` and just use the "first" part of that split to be the grouping key. For more complex manipulation you might need to employ `mapReduce` at this time. Anything that relies on "regular expressions" for pattern matching how to determine the part of the string for grouping is currently outside of the aggregation framework operator capabilities. But is actually due for future release.

Comment: I'd suggest that the client that inserts the data will trim redundant `/`. It will be much easier to run the aggregation this way

Comment: @Neil Lunn. The string can be any valid uri with or without trailing slash. Thank you for the pointing direction. I will check docs about mapReduce and split functions

Comment: @Hagai I fully agree with you. If I cannot do this, I will have to delete the last slash. But theoretically, there may be different pages. But that will be other "story".